# Simple math function not working

Tags: c++, math

I am pretty new to c++ but I am trying to set up a really simple c++ project. Below you can find the code so far. But what I am having trouble with is the math function `p = n^2-8n+7;`. Any suggestions how I could improve it??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
using namespace std;

int main() {

/* Variable Declaration */
int p,n,i;

for (n=0; n<100; n++) {

/* Math Function */
p = n^2-8n+7;

/* Check if prime */
for (i=2; i<p; i++) { 
    if (!(p%i)) break;
    else cout << "(" << n << "," << p << ");" << endl;
}

}

/* Ready */
printf("\n\n\a");
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You should look at the differences between C++ math and calculator math.

Comment: It becomes apparent when you look through and realize C++ has no power operator, and does have a multiplication operator.

Comment: Illustrates how easy it is to mix up elements of different languages with math operations. "8n" is math notation and "^" is raise to power in VB.NET, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change

```
 n^2-8n+7;
```

to

```
p = n * n - 8 *n + 7;
```

You are missing the ***** for multiplication and also  instead of ^ you either need to mutliply two times or use pow function

Answer (score 6):

To get square use `n*n` instead of `n^2`.  `^` is the bitwise xor operator.

Comment: For completeness, there's an `8n` in there being treated as the number 8 with `n` as a suffix. +1 if you add that part in. http://ideone.com/9c8l9

Comment: I missed that.. Thanks @chris

Answer (score 5):

The operator ^ is not equal to potency, but rather the binary operator 'XOR'.

For n^2 either use (n*n) or, for higher potencies, the premade 'pow' function, which is described here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/

For your example, that would be pow(n, 2);
8n doesn't work either, you need to write it fully as '8 * n'.

Comment: For square power, to save yourself typing and the world from global warming with wasting of CPU cycles in the expensive `pow()` function (what is usually paid with carbon dioxide on the atmosphere), you should just go with `n*n`.

Comment: @lvella Which is why I explicitely stated, that it's mainly for 'higher potencies', even though a plain 'for'-loop has the very same effect. I just meant to bring the existence of this function to his attention.

Comment: I would not expect `pow(n, 2)` to actually result in a call to `pow`.